# How to make sure child processes have correct user ID?

Tags: linux, bash, user-management

As a etude, I wrote a quick-and-dirty bash script to set a radio alarm a few months ago. It sets a cron/at-job to start streaming an internet radio at as specified time (I use mplayer), and records the job id in a file for easy undoing. However, as it stands the logic to turn off a running alarm is simply to kill of the most recent couple of mplayer instances. This is potentially a problem if you're watching a video at the time the alarm goes off, or running a batch job converting audio or video files...

So I thought I'd create a designated virtual user for running this script, and, instead of killing the most recent mplayer instances, kill all and only those invoked by this user. I thus created a user `radiowecker` and invoke the script with `sudo -u radiowecker /var/lib/radiowecker/wecker $1`. However, this doesn't seem to do the job: While the `at`-job does show up as `radiowecker`'s, the mplayer instances it spawns are filed under my UID. How do I ensure the child processes are also filed as `radiowecker`'s?

```
if [ $2 ]; 
    then stream="$2"
    else stream=http://mp3stream1.apasf.apa.at:8000;
fi
if [ $1 ]; then
    # with argument, set new radio alarm using 'at' and log the at-job-id
    remove_log_when_playing="rm ~/.local/bin/weckerlogs/${*} "
    play_radio="mplayer $stream -cache 1024"
    and="&&"
    show_running="touch ~/.local/bin/alarm_running"
    printf "$remove_log_when_playing && $show_running && $play_radio" | at "${*}" \
    && echo $(atq | sort -nr | { read first last ; echo $first ; }) >> ~/.local/bin/weckerlogs/"${*}"
else
    if [[ $(pgrep mplayer) && -e ~/.local/bin/alarm_running ]]; then
        rm ~/.local/bin/alarm_running
        # turn off running mplayer, assumed to be called from an earlier alarm
        for i in 0 1; do
            for id in $(pgrep mplayer)
                do WECKER=$id
            done
            kill $WECKER
        done
    else 
        # turning off an alarm in the future has its own tool
        echo "No active mplayer instances found."
        echo "To turn off a future alarm, instead"
        echo "use 'wecker-aus' <time>!"
        echo "Currently set alarms:"
        ls ~/.local/bin/weckerlogs/
    fi
fi
```

turn off future alarm:

```
#/bin/bash
log=~/.local/bin/weckerlogs/"${*}"
atrm $(cat "$log") 
rm "$log"
```

Comment: Have you looked at `sudo -u user ...` to insure mplayer is invoked as the user you intend?

Comment: I did `sudo -u user ...` to invoke the bash script, expecting all child processes to be signed with that user. The `at`-job was indeed signed with that user, but the mplayer instances it envoked were running on me.

Comment: Also look at the `--set-home` option (may be default) and make sure your install does not have the `--preserv-env` option set by default.